# How to pass a Matrix in Simulink using S-Function

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink, s-function

I have written a S-Function in MATLAB. Now I want to pass a Matrix into the input via the 'simin' Source. I have initialized the time of the simin variable with 
`simin.time = 0`
and the values are stored in a dynamically sized matrix. So for example `simin.signals.values = ones(4)`. 
Now MATLAB tells me that 'time and data values must have the same number of rows'. I understand that but how can I pass a matrix in one timestep? 
And is it possible to simulate a S-Function only once and not cyclic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the dimensions of the signal, see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html?refresh=true)

[image: Matlab Docs]

I've done a simple test, simulate for 10 seconds and it all looks good.

```
simin.time = 0;
simin.signals.values = ones(4)
simin.signals.dimensions = [4,4];
```

[image: Simple Model]